# Finding value of k when line does not intersect

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=-1+kx+k$ neither touches nor intercepts the curve $f(x)=\log(x)$ then minimum value of $k$ is? ($\log$ is the natural logarithm).

My working :no idea at all .Just calculated the slope of both functions.

Comment: The minimum does not exist. Are you sure about the "non touching" condition? Or should it be "intersects the curve f(x)=log(x) in at most one point"?

Comment: Yes  i have tried this lot.can maximum value exists

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks for the smallest $k$ for which the line $y=kx+k-1$ lies above the graph of $y=\ln x$.
In other words, we would like to find the smallest real number $k$ satisfying 
$$ kx+k-1 ~\ge~ \ln x ~~~~~~~\Longleftrightarrow~~~~~~~  k~\ge~ \frac{1+\ln x}{x+1} $$
for all real numbers $x$.
This amounts to maximizing $g(x)=\frac{1+\ln x}{x+1}$. 
The resulting maximum value then is $W(1)$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function.

Hence for $k=W(1)$ the two curves touch.
For $k<W(1)$ they intersect in two points.
For $k>W(1)$ they do not intersect at all.

Comment: Sir will you provide more information about Lambert function.